# Algebra 1 - probability question with deck of cards where you need to find number of queens of spades but it’s a special deck of cards

Tags: probability

Freddy the Ghoul has a special deck of cards that has 54 cards. This deck has the property that if Freddy chooses any 13 cards from it, they will always contain a queen of spades. If Freddy randomly chooses 26 cards from his deck, what's the Smallest number of queens of spades he could have chosen?

Comment: What happens if there are exactly $~13~$ cards such that none of these $~13~$ cards are the Queen of Spades?

Comment: I suppose transmogrification will take place !